# Where should I put the files generated from Pyqt4 scripts?

Tags: macos, pyqt4

I used the python scripts to generate the files for Pyqt4 but they are in the folder where the script was located and I don't know where to put them. This was on Osx High Sierra. I believe that they would belong somewhere in the /usr/ file but have no clue where under the file it should fall

Comment: What scripts do you mean?

Comment: Please paste your code.